Common mode choke necessary for USB 5V supply?
I'm designing a boost converter for an audio application that is supplied by a 5V usb supply. Just the USB supply is used and not the data lines. According to this application note from Wuerth, only a ferrite bead is used in the 5V line and common mode chokes are used for EMI suppression in the data lines. Since my application is sensitive to noise, I'm wondering if a common mode choke is needed in the 5V supply line that supplies the boost converter. I'm not concerned about CM noise propagating back to the USB supply but rather propagating to the boost converter output.

What connects to your device? Even if USB, in and of itself, doesn't need CM filtering, the overall system may still benefit from a CMC in this position. || EMC is a complex, interconnected topic, and EMC problems are holistic in nature.  There is generally very little that can be said about a problem without also completely describing the setup and environment: schematics and PCB layout are most likely required for a reasonably complete and confident answer.

It's a headphone amplifier. So first an audio amplifier and then wired headphones.

Amplifier? Or media player? -- If there's no other connections, nor a radio, it's not going to be playing very much!

The audio signal comes into the amplifier via a media player, or phone and out to the headphones.
